# Error: unexpected '}' bothers me all day

Tags: r

I am trying to deal with an unexpected `}` in all day but I cannot get it to work. When I run this code,

```
read<-function(file){ 
+     df<-read.table(file=file,header=FALSE,sep = ",", na.strings = "NULL")  
+     names(df)<-c("date","Open","High","Low","Close")                       
+     dl<-split(df,format(as.POSIXct(df$date),'%Y-%m-%d'))                   
+     lapply(dl,function(item){                                              
+         xts(item[-1],order.by = as.POSIXct(item$date))
+     })
+     }
```

I get this error:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"+         xts(item[-1],order.by = as.POSIXct(item$date))
+     }"
> +     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "+     }"
```

Comment: @Psidom I’ve rolled back your change since I think that this is the crux of the question.

Comment: See the "+" in the error message?  You need to remove all those plus signs.  My guess is that you copy/pasted to/from the console and didn't remove them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think it makes sense.

Comment: Are you copying the code from Rstudio console to the editor and then compiling the file? Rstudio adds `+` in the beginning of line to show continuation of previous line.  That `+` isn't part of syntax. You can set `continue` option to `"  "` to disable`+` at the line beginning in Console.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are all right! Thank you! Then if i want to read a csv file using this function, how should I do? Can you give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a syntax that shouldn't break. It does look like you're pasting in "+" marks from somewhere else and that's causing the problem.

```
read <- function(file) {
  df <- read.table(file=file, header=FALSE, sep = ",", na.strings = "NULL")
  names(df) <- c("date","Open","High","Low","Close")
  dl <- split(df, format(as.POSIXct(df$date), '%Y-%m-%d'))
  lapply(dl, function(item){ xts(item[-1], order.by = as.POSIXct(item$date))})
}
```

Comment: I think he was running the code line by line and then copied the code from the console.